# Emulate SSH forwarding to a Docker container

Tags: docker, ssh

I have a server (let's call it `host`) that runs Docker and a container, (call it `guest`). `guest` runs an SSH server and exposes it to `host` on port 5000, but `host` does not expose it to the outside world.

I can SSH into `host` from my machine. I can then SSH into localhost:5000 which gets me into `guest`. I can automate these two steps by using an SSH config like:

```
Host guest
    HostName localhost:5000
    ProxyJump host
```

Now typing `ssh guest` from my machine would automatically connect to `guest` using `host` as a proxy.

However, best practices is to avoid using SSH and use tools like `docker exec` instead. However, if I remove the SSH server from `guest`, the SSH config above will break, and I will go back to having to do the 2 steps of `SSH host`, then `docker exec guest`.

Is it possible to somehow set up Docker so that proxied SSH connections are automatically convert into `docker exec guest` commands?

Comment: What program actually runs in the container?  Can you avoid needing shell access to it so often?

Comment: @DavidMaze `docker run` runs it, and I cannot avoid needing shell access.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using [ssh tunnelling](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example) options?

On my servers I use:

`ssh -M -S my-ctrl-socket -fnNT -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -L /tmp/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ${SERVER_USER}@${SERVER_IP}`

Breaking down this command:

- `-M` places the ssh client into master mode for connection sharing
- `-S my-ctrl-socket` specifies the location of a control socket for connection sharing, as an actual file in memory, in this case called `my-ctrl-socket`
- `-fnNT` can be broken down into:

  - `-f` Requests ssh to go to background just before command execution
  - `-n` Redirects stdin from /dev/null (actually, prevents reading from stdin).  This must be used when ssh is run in the background.
  - `-N` Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just forwarding ports.
  - `-T` Disable pseudo-terminal allocation
- `-o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes` sets additional flags
- `-L local_socket:remote_socket` Specifies that connections to the given TCP port or Unix socket on the local (client) host are to be forwarded to the given host and port, or Unix socket, on the remote side.
- `${SERVER_USER}@${SERVER_IP}` is the server user and the server IP.

Summing up, this command allows me to run docker commands - like `docker exec [..]` - in the docker socket of the target host from my terminal, effectively allowing me to avoid doing the two step process mentioned in the question. [Here](https://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2018/04/30/forwarding-the-docker-socket-via-a-ssh-tunnel-to-execute-docker-commands-locally/) you can find an additional example.

Comment: Can you explain what all the arguments do?

Comment: I tried to update my answer, let me know if it is any clearer, meanwhile I will look for some further example to provide you.